# G finite group with the following characteristics

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups

G is closed finite group with an associative operator with the following parametres/characterstics:

For each $x,y\in G$ if $ax = ay$ then $x = y$ for each $a\in G$
For each $w,z\in G$ if $wa = za$ then $w = z$ for each $a\in G$

Why does that implies that there is identity unite and opposite ?

My suggestion: 
we choose $e,a,b\in G$ and write: $ea = eb$ then a=b and accroding to second characteristic we choose the same e,a,b but now $ae = be$ then $a = b$
So e as identity unite is in the group and his own characteristics are true by the given charactrestics, so he is the identity.

About the opposite, I dont sure how to express it correctly and formally. I mean if we multiple by it (if it exists) from right and from left we'll get the sentences below as true, but I stil dont understand why it's existence is inevitable? 
I mean, so maybe there isnt an opposite but the characteristics are true by definition.

Can anybody show it to me taking elements in g and showing how that characteristics conclude about the identity and the oposite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose any $a\in G$. Then as the equation $ax=a$ has unique solution in $G$, let the solution be $a'$. Hence $aa'=a$.

Now choose $b\in G$, $b$ arbitrary. Then note that $ab=(aa')b=a(a'b)$.

But this means that the equation $ax=ab$ has more than one solution if $a'b\neq b$, contradicting the hypothesis. Hence $a'b=b$.

But $b$ was arbitrary, therefore $a'$ is the left identity in $G$.

Similarly you can show that if $a''$ is the unique solution to $ya=a$ then $a''$ is the right identity in $G$.

The right identity is unique since otherwise $ax=a$ would have two solutions. Same for the left identity.

Thus let $e_L$ and $e_R$ be the unique left and right identities in $G$. Then $e_L=e_Le_R$ (by property of $e_R$) $=e_R$ (by property of $e_L$). So the identity is one and unique. Call it $e$.

Now $ax=e$ has unique solution call it $a_1$, giving the right inverse of $a$. Again $ya=e$ has unique solution call it $a_2$ giving left inverse of $a$.

Shall I leave it to you to check that $a_1=a_2$?

Comment: the "unique solution" concluded because of the hypothesis, right ? 
because x = concrete something ?

Comment: Yes you are right. :)

Comment: Ok, thank you, I got it.

Comment: Please do not forget to check that the left and right inverses are indeed equal.

Comment: In the second sentence of this answer, "has a unique solution" needs justification. The hypothesis of the question gives us that this equation has at most one solution, but it doesn't say that a solution exists at all.  As far as I can see, to justify the existence of a solution, one needs to use the finiteness of $G$.

Comment: Yes it follows from the fact that $G$ is finite and cancellation laws apply. I thought this was evident.